# Как передать в функцию 1 объект вместо нескольких его свойств? c#

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет. У меня есть вот такая строка кода:

```
 await space.Insert(TarantoolTuple.Create(model.Id, model.Login, model.Balance));
```

Туда нужно передать необходимые параметры для вставки в базу через ",".
Все эти параметры, это свойства объекта model.
Однако если я передаю туда сам объект, то действие не выполняется.

```
public async Task<UserModel> Insert(UserModel model)
        {
            model.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            await space.Insert(TarantoolTuple.Create(model));
            return model;
        }
```

Как можно решить эту проблему? 
Эта функция позже будет обобщённой, и не хочется для каждого экземпляра прописывать все свойства только для этой функции.

Comment: Извлечь интерфейс, объявить класс реалзирующим интерфейс, передать объект, но в сигнатуре метода указать не конкретный класс, а имя интерфейса.

Comment: @AK Можешь с 1-2 переменными в ответе привести пример? Мне не совсем понятна эта фраза "но в сигнатуре метода указать не конкретный класс, а имя интерфейса". Спасибо).

Comment: `TarantoolTuple.Create` - ??

Comment: @Igor это синтаксис коннектора такой. Создаётся Tuple для вставки объекта в базу.

Comment: `TarantoolTuple.Create` - этот метод ваш или из какой-то библиотеки? Судя по названию он создаёт кортеж - какой именно: `System.Tuple` или `System.ValueTuple`? Или вообще какой-то собственный тип?

Comment: `space.Insert` - этот метод ваш или из какой-то библиотеки?..

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это не мой метод. Из библиотеки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вот так он описан. https://i.imgur.com/YWz8CL6.png https://i.imgur.com/GTaEA00.png

Comment: Какая библиотека? Дайте наконец ссылку на офф документацию! [Оно?](https://github.com/progaudi/progaudi.tarantool)

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://github.com/progaudi/progaudi.tarantool/blob/master/src/progaudi.tarantool/Model/TarantoolTuple.cs) легко можно написать метод-хелпер, принимающий ваш конкретный тип UserModel и возвращающий тупл. Но это имеет смысл только если он нужен в нескольких местах.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128422/discussion-between-aofa-group-and-alexander-petrov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `TarantoolTuple.Create` принимает отдельные значения и на их основе создаёт экземляр класса `TarantoolTuple`.

Можно создать метод-хелпер, который будет выполнять эту работу:

```
TarantoolTuple<string, string, decimal> CreateTuple(UserModel model)
{
    return TarantoolTuple.Create(model.Id, model.Login, model.Balance);
}
```

Теперь можно его использовать так:

```
await space.Insert(CreateTuple(model));
```

---

Другой вариант - написать метод расширения для класса `Space`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task<DataResponse<TarantoolTuple<string, string, decimal>[]>> InsertModel(this Space space, UserModel model)
    {
        return space.Insert(TarantoolTuple.Create(model.Id, model.Login, model.Balance));
    }
}
```

Код с его использованием становится ещё короче:

```
await space.InsertModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это твой метод, то сделай так чтобы он принимал обьект класса UserModel:

```
TarantoolTuple.Create(UserModel model);
```

Если это не твой метод и у этого метода нет перегрузки которая принимает класс UserModel, то никак. Потому-что этот метод принимает параметры:

```
TarantoolTuple.Create(string id, string login, string balance);
```

И уже дальше с ними манипулирует.

Comment: это не мой метод. Из библиотеки. Вот так он описан. i.imgur.com/YWz8CL6.png i.imgur.com/GTaEA00.png

Comment: @AofAGroup ну можешь тогда типизировать что передаешь - TarantoolTuple.Create<UserModel>(model);

Comment: @Міша это обобщённый класс. Я не могу типизировать. В примере он еще был не обобщён. Забыл указать это.